# Unwanted gap between 2 div's

Tags: css, asp.net

I place 2 Gridviews next to each other and can't avoid the 2 pixel gap between the two. Both Gridviews get fed by the same data and I want to create the illusion that they actually are just one; with the left one fixed in position, while the right one being scrollable. I am a perfectionist and these 2 Pixels are torturing me, while I'm trying to solve this for hours

This is what I do:

```
<table style="width:1400px;border-collapse:collapse;border:none;">
   <tr>
      <td style="width:600px;text-align:right;">
         <div id="GV_FollowUpFix" runat="server" style="width:600px;overflow:hidden;border:none;">   
            <asp:GridView ID="GridViewFollowUpFix" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" BorderWidth="0">
               <Columns....>
            </asp:GridView>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width:800px;text-align:left;">
         <div id="GV_FollowUpMove" runat="server" style="width:800px;overflow-x:scroll;border:none;">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridViewFollowUpMove" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" BorderWidth="0">
               <Columns....>
            </asp:GridView>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you looking for?

if you ask what code I have made then it is `padding:0;` for the `td`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/djxy7eup/31/) to play-around.

```html
<table style="width:1400px;border-collapse:collapse;border:0px solid red;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:600px;text-align:right;padding:0;">
      <div id="GV_FollowUpFix" runat="server" style="width:600px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid black;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewFollowUpFix" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" BorderWidth="0">

        </asp:GridView>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="width:800px;text-align:left;border-spacing: 0px;padding:0;">
      <div id="GV_FollowUpMove" runat="server" style="width:800px;overflow-x:scroll;border:0px solid teal;">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewFollowUpMove" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" BorderWidth="0">

        </asp:GridView>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This adds a border around both elements while I want to get rid of a gap that I don't have a clue where it is coming from. As I can't exclude that the Gridviews are responsible for that gap I can't transcribe this for the fiddle

Comment: Border is just for reference, you can see it here I have removed the border: https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/djxy7eup/34/  I just tried to fix the code with what you have shared, so I had to add border to differentiate the 2 divs. Hope you got it now.